# android нету интерфейса OnMapReadyCallback для импорта

Tags: android, google-maps

Нету интерфейса `OnMapReadyCallback` в пакете `com.google.android.gms.maps`, другие классы есть! Где скачать библиотеку?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте создать проект начиная с map activity. Если же проект уже большой, возможно просто создать map activity из стандартных, там сразу включён этот интерфейс.
[Пример](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/easy-android-maps-part-1)

Comment: Не совсем понял. Можете, пожалуйста, обьяснить подробнее

Comment: @Devel0 обновил ответ